# How to fix PyCharm inspection warnings in bulk, e.g. convert all "raise" statements to Python 3 syntax?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, intellij-idea, pycharm, refactoring

The question is: How to apply PyCharm inspection quick-fixes in bulk? [Presumably the same features are also in IntelliJ, CLion, et al.]

I'm porting a Python 2.7 code base to Python 3.8 and want to make one kind of change at a time [e.g. replace `raise Exception, "message"` with `raise Exception("message")`], review it, and test it. Eventually I'll try using [python-modernize](https://python-modernize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), but can PyCharm make specific types of compatibility fixes in bulk?

You can [configure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/code-inspection.html) PyCharm's `Code compatibility inspection` to check for, say, Python 2.7 + 3.7 + and 3.8, then [run that inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-inspections.html) on your entire project or a smaller scope. Or use the `Code` > `Run Inspection by Name...` menu command to run the `Code compatibility inspection` with a temporary choice of options and scope. The warnings will list items like these:

- `Python version 3.7, 3.8 do not support this syntax`
- `Python version 3.7, 3.8 do not have module __builtin__`
- `Python version 3.7, 3.8 do not have method xrange`
- `Python version 3.7, 3.8 do not have module cPickle`
- `dict.iterkeys(), dict.iteritems() and dict.itervalues() methods are not available in py3`
- `basestring type is not available in py3`

If you select an example of these first two types of warnings, PyCharm can [apply a "quick-fix﻿"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/resolving-problems.html) like `Convert raise statement to supported form`. For the other warnings listed above, it can only offer to suppress the warning :-(

I have hundreds of these! How to fix them in bulk?

Answer (score 1):

There's a cute trick.

1. In the `Inspection Results` tool window, click the `Expand All` button (or type Command-+ or whatever the equivalent is in your keymap).
2. Type Command-F (or the equivalent) to Find an example of your chosen type of inspection warning, e.g. search for `syntax`.

   - (PyCharm won't open a "Find" dialog for this but you can still type the search text and it will display that in an overlay.)
3. Do `Edit` > `Select All` (or type Command-A or equivalent).
4. Now click the button to apply the quick-fix!

(If you know how to make PyCharm fix the other compatibility warnings, please add more Answers. Otherwise, it's on to `modernize`.)